# Не работает форма отправки ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть сайт [proteksstroy.ru](http://proteksstroy.ru) на нем есть несколько форм , точнее форма, а другие просто ссылаются на ее id. Так вот эта самая форма не хочет отправляться со слайдера, после ввода данных происходит перезагрузка и ничего не отправляется. А вот по вызову данной формы через другие формы, данная форма почему-то работает корректно и все данные отправляются, хотя форма одна и та же, прошу помочь с данной проблемой.

Вот сама форма:

```
<form method="POST" id="callbacks" class="callback clearfix">
  <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="ООО ПРОТЭКССТРОЙ">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Вам оставили заявку на сайте proteks">
  <h4>Бесплатная консультация<br> по Вашему обьекту</h4>
  <label><input type="text" name="Имя" placeholder="Ваше имя" required /</label>
  <label><input type="text" name="Телефон" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required /></label>
  <button class="button" id="click">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

А вот аякс перехватчик:

```html
$("#callbacks").submit(function() { //Change
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "mail.php",
   data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
   $.fancybox ( { href: '#popup_order' } );
   $(this).trigger("reset");
  });
  return false;
 });
```

Очень прошу вас помочь, уже очень долго не могу понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на странице целых 5 форм с #callbacks. Поэтому код, предложенный Vanya Avchyan у вас не работает, хотя он верный:

```
$("#callbacks").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "mail.php",
         data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
         $.fancybox ( { href: '#popup_order' } );
         $(_this).trigger("reset");
    });
});
```

[image: скриншот вашего кода]

Слушатель события вешается только на первую из форм. 
Обратите внимание, что аттрибут id по стандартам HTML должен быть уникальным на странице, в этом вся его суть. Это уникальный, однозначный идентификатор элемента.

В вашем случае стоит или избавиться от лишних "клонов", или вешать событие не по id, а используя класс, например

```
$("form.callback").submit(...)
```

Но у вас не только #callbacks формы содержат класс callback, поэтому его следует заменить каким-то другим, определяющим именно нужные формы.

А вот одинаковый id уберите в любом случае. Он вам точно не нужен. JS для этих элементов все равно не работает, а CSS (если он привязан к этому id) несложно перевести на классы.

Answer (score 3):

Потому Что пока доходит до return false событие уже срабатывает.Надо его остановить прежде что либо делать.

И this формы не предают так как вы предавали.Потому Что this в функции которой мы используем ссылается на этот объект.В вашем случае он ссылаться на callback функцию переменной в методе done.

```
$("#callbacks").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $.fancybox ( { href: '#popup_order' } );
        $(_this).trigger("reset");
    });
});
```

Comment: все также не работает(

Comment: @Руслан Демин  Посмотри как разъясняет Иван Пшеницын.id должны быть уникальны,когда ставишь id убедись что на данной странице он уникальный,то есть не повторяется

Answer (score 0):

```html
$("#callbacks").submit(function() { //Change
var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "mail.php",
   data: data
  }).done(function() {
   $.fancybox ( { href: '#popup_order' } );
   $(this).trigger("reset");
  });
  return false;
 });
```

у вас внутри запроса $(this) уже не ваша форма

Comment: К сожалению, не взлетело, все также(